# echo iframe inside value

Tags: iframe, youtube

I'm still a newbie and I'm really having a hard time on this. How can I be able to echo the embedded youtube video to the page when the 1st checkbox is selected? Please help. Thanks.

```
<form action="" method="post">
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="<?php echo "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/TnxUOdAhAdk\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>"; ?>">Video1</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 2">Video2</label>
  <label><input type="checkbox" name="check_list[]" value="value 3">Video3</label>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>


<?php
if(!empty($_POST['check_list'])) {
    foreach($_POST['check_list'] as $check) {
        echo $check;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you using javascript/jquery instead of php since you already know your youtube links. [This link will give you more info about this](http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/).

Anyhow here is a php code that might help you:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form action='index.php' method='post'>
        <input type='checkbox' name='video1' value='true'/>Show Video1
        <br/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='video2' value='true'/>Show Video2
        <br/>
        <input type='checkbox' name='video3' value='true'/>Show Video3
        <br/>
        <input type='submit' value='Show Videos'/>
    </form>

    <?php
    if (isset($_POST['video1'])) {
        echo "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/TnxUOdAhAdk\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['video2'])) {
        echo "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/2mKxsC2oi5s\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    if (isset($_POST['video3'])) {
        echo "<iframe width=\"640\" height=\"360\" src=\"http://www.youtube.com/embed/tC2fjzWIM-Y\" frameborder=\"0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>";
        echo "<br/>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```